# Codename one TestFlight Missing Beta Entitlement

Tags: codenameone, testflight

Hello
I try to upload a build to Itunes Connect and share it with my team by TestFlight. The upload is OK but when i open the build, Itunes said that he's missing beta entitlement. 
I've checked "includeTestFlight" in my IDE and also i have created a Distribution App Store Profile. When i take a look over my embbed.mobileprovision, it is specified `<key>beta-reports-active</key><true/>`

[image]

In Itunes Connect, no avalaible build appears with TestFlight : 
[image]

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testflight is only included in release builds, did you build an appstore version?

Is your pro account still in order?

Comment: Yes, it's a realease build i've send. Do i need a pro account in codename one to use TestFlight build option ?

Comment: Yes, it's part of the crash protection package.

Comment: Ok , thanks for your help ! :)
(Maybe it should be clearly explained in pro subscription in your website ?)